# Abtract class derived from a nomal class. Is that valid?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, overriding

Is the following a valid design in C++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
    virtual void SomeMethod() {
        std::cout<<"Do Something"<<std::endl;
    }
};

struct Der : public Base {
    virtual void SomeMethod() override = 0;
};

struct DerDer : Der {
    virtual void SomeMethod() override
    {
        std::cout<<"Do something derived."<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto x = std::unique_ptr<Base>(new DerDer);
    x->SomeMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

It works on g++ 6.2.

I'm deriving from a normal class, converting that method to abstract, and then overriding it after deriving again.

**Is it correct in C++ to derive from a class, and then turn an implemented method back to abstract?**

The reason I need to do this, is that in a big program, to which I'm adding features, I'm trying to [avoid a diamond model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979185/consequences-of-changing-inheritance-to-virtual). To do that, I'm planning to put all common methods in the class `Der`, and make everything inherit from it, without messing with the `Base` class.

Comment: `Der::SomeMethod` should also be `override`. You should call the method via a `Base *`: http://ideone.com/QJ5su3

Comment: @mch Better? :) ...

Answer (score 0):

That's legal.

But if you want avoid the diamon model, there are [another workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943401/ambiguous-workaround-for-multiinheritance/39943555)

Comment: The answers to the linked question show how to create a diamond shaped hierarchy. Not how to avoid it.

Comment: @user2079303 I was gonna say that. You beat me to it!

Comment: Uh, i think that right sentence is: "avoid the problems of the diamon model" :)

Comment: @amchacon not quite technically correct either. The *problem* that the OP of the linked question has is that there are two base classes of same type, which results in ambiguity. The *solution* to that problem is to create a "diamond model". The diamond model also has problems sure, but those are not avoided by virtual inheritance. Virtual inheritance is what creates the "diamond model".

Answer (score 0):

absolutely legal. Consider it as just implementation of pure virtual function if you like.
See discussion here [pure virtual function with implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation)

Answer (score -1):

Technically there would not be any problem but it is never a good design when you inherit interface (or abstract class) from a concrete class.

If you are going to provide some common functionality in Der, you can use composition. Because your class Der would be like a utility class. Don't make der class as abstract class.

```
Class DerDer : class base
{
  private der ptrUtilityObj;
}
```

In future, might be some new developer will confuse that he should introduce new functionality in Base class or Der class.